# Map Is Not a Function Error on React json import

Tags: reactjs

I know this issue comes up a lot but I can't seem to find an answer here or elsewhere to fix  my React JS 'Map Is Not a Function' error.

Here is an extract from Json data file 'movielocations.json':

```
[   
    {
        "RegionId": 1,
        "RegionName": "MALTA",
        "LocationPlaceId": 44,
        "LocationPlaceName": "Attard",
        "locationsites": [
            {
                "LocationSiteId": 114,
                "LocationSiteName": "Attard",
                "Latitude": 0.0,
                "Longitude": 0.0        
                
            },
            {
                "LocationSiteId": 109,
                "LocationSiteName": "Flower Power Garden Centre",
                "Latitude": 35.89904,
                "Longitude": 14.42775               
            },
            {
                "LocationSiteId": 110,
                "LocationSiteName": "Tiq Durumblat",
                "Latitude": 35.89928,
                "Longitude": 14.42952               
            }
        ]
        
        etc etc..
    },
```

I simply want to import the data to state 'Locations' and then later list in a table.
The error occurs on 'Locations.map..' in the Render()
Problem is it is not setting the state in the LoadLocations() method so is trying to render an empty array.....I think?
Here is the file...

```
import MovieLocations from '../data/movielocations.json'

class LocationsList extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
            super(props);

   // const { region } = useParams()
   
   this.mounted = false
    
    this.state =({
      loadingInformation: false,
      Locations: [],
      Region: 'MALTA' 
    })
}
    
componentDidMount(){

this.mounted = true
this.LoadLocations()
}

componentWillUnmount () {
      this.mounted = false
    }

 LoadLocations() {
      const { Locations, loadingInformation } = this.state

      if (loadingInformation) {
        return
      }
     const {Region} = this.state

     this.setState({ loadingInformation: true, Locations:[] }) 

      let regionUpperCase = Region.toUpperCase()      
     
             MovieLocations.filter(locations => locations.RegionName == regionUpperCase).map(filteredlocations => {                  
                
                  if (this.mounted) {
                       this.setState( { loadingInformation: false, Locations : filteredlocations })   // NOT SETTING STATE !?                  
                       return  
                  }   
    })
}

render() {
      const {Locations, Region} = this.state
      let regionUpperCase = Region.toUpperCase()

      let locationsList = '' 
      if (Locations){
            locationsList =  Locations.map(locations => { // ERROR HERE !
                  return ( 
                        <tr key = { locations.LocationPlaceId }>
                              <td><Link to={`/movie/${locations.LocationPlaceId}`}>{locations.LocationPlaceName}</Link></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>TODO WIKI URL</td>
                  <td></td>
                  </tr>  ) 
            })
      }

   return <div>
        <Container>
      <div className="flex-sidebyside"><h2>{`${regionUpperCase} - LOCATIONS` } </h2>
      <img src={Region === 'malta'? maltaLogo : manchesterLogo}
      alt={Region + ' logo'}
      title={Region + ' logo'}
      width="25px" 
      height="25px"     />
      </div>
      <table className="table">
            <thead>
                  <tr>
                        <th>Location Place</th>
                        <th>Location Site</th>
                        <th>Wikipedia</th>
                           <th></th>
                  </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                  {locationsList}            
    
       </tbody>
       </table>
      </Container>
      </div>     
}
} 
export default LocationsList;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem in your loadLocations method :

```
LoadLocations() {     
    ....
    MovieLocations.filter(locations =>locations.RegionName==regionUpperCase)
                  .map(filteredlocations => {                  
                  if (this.mounted) {
                       this.setState({ 
                                      loadingInformation: false, 
                                       Locations : filteredlocations
                                      })   // NOT SETTING STATE !?                  
                       return  
                    }   
             })
}
```

the  MovieLocations.filter() will return an array of filteredLocations but you are using  a map on this filteredLocations so in the locations will be just one item not array.
so you have to do something like this:

```
const filteredlocations = MovieLocations.filter(locations=> 
                                             locations.RegionName==regionUpperCase)
                                  
      if (this.mounted) {
         this.setState({ 
                       loadingInformation: false, 
                       Locations : filteredlocations
                       })                     
      }
```

Comment: Thank you that has worked.  I had been used to using filter and map together when simply iterating through and directly outputting the results rather than storing to state, so getting the procedures mixed up!  Makes sense now, thanks again